# How are things from my friends selected to appear in my news feed?

Tags: facebook, news-feed

I want more insight into how Facebook decides what to show in my news feed. For instance, for one of my friends, I cannot see in my news feed (NOTE: the "Show in news feed" option is indeed enabled and set to "All Updates" for this friend):

- When she becomes friend when someone
- When she is tagged by someone
- When she likes something
- When somebody else writes on her wall

But I can see in my news feed posts made by her that are not public. Also, I know that she is active since I can see that she has been tagged recently and I can see the posts made by others if I go look directly to her wall. I also know that she sometimes "likes" things because if I go to some particular photos, I can see her name appear among the people who liked it. It's just that it never appeared on my news feed.

How does that work?